# Validating xml via xsd

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xsd

I'm new to XSD, so please help. I've created some XML using "for xml path" in SQL Server Management Studio 2008. It looks like:
[image]

I've read some literature, where after creating such an xml, I'm supposed to run this:
[image]

But it doesn't work. As I know after saving this file in xml and clicking it twice, it should open xml in browser. But it doesn't. What is wrong? primary key is ReferenceCode. I've created xml using this query:

```
   select p.ReferenceCode
         ,p.LastName
         ,p.FirstName
         ,p.BirthDate
         ,p.BirthPlace
         ,(
           select d.Type
                 ,d.Series
                 ,d.Number
                 ,d.IssueDate
                 ,d.IssueAuthority
             from #Document d
            where d.ReferenceCode = p.ReferenceCode
              for xml path ('Document'),root('Documents'),Type
          )
         ,(
           select a.Type
                 ,a.Street
             from #Address a
            where a.ReferenceCode = p.ReferenceCode
              for xml path ('Address'),root('Addresses'),Type
          )
         ,(
           select h.Number
             from #Phone h
            where h.ReferenceCode = p.ReferenceCode
              for xml path ('Phone'),root('Phone'),Type
          )
     from #Person p
      for xml path ('Person'),root('Root')
```

Thanks in advance

```
<Root>
  <Person>
    <ReferenceCode>10000007462</ReferenceCode>
    <LastName>Артамонова</LastName>
    <FirstName>Галина</FirstName>
    <BirthDate>1961-07-19</BirthDate>
    <BirthPlace>РОССИЙСКАЯ ФЕДЕРАЦИЯ, д. Криуша Староюрьевского р-на Тамбовской обл.</BirthPlace>
    <Documents>
      <Document>
        <Type>21</Type>
        <Series>4508</Series>
        <Number>685129</Number>
        <IssueDate>2006-08-16</IssueDate>
        <IssueAuthority>ОВД р-на Чертаново-Центральное г. Москвы,</IssueAuthority>
      </Document>
    </Documents>
    <Addresses>
      <Address>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Street>Днепропетровская ул</Street>
      </Address>
      <Address>
        <Type>1</Type>
        <Street>Декабристов ул</Street>
      </Address>
      <Address>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <Street>Днепропетровская ул</Street>
      </Address>
      <Address>
        <Type>2</Type>
        <Street>Декабристов ул</Street>
      </Address>
    </Addresses>
    <Phones>
      <Phone>
        <Number>907-09-33      </Number>
      </Phone>
      <Phone>
        <Number>+7(903)1780367 </Number>
      </Phone>
    </Phones>
  </Person>
</Root>
```

Comment: Please never use images for code or data.

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". What doesn't work? Does `xsd` give an error? Does it not create files? Does it create the wrong files? I would try it out, but I'm not going to retype what you've posted as an image.

Comment: I've added text format. XSD just not created, that is all. Command prompt executes without error

Comment: I can't reproduce this using version 7.0a or 8.1 of the Windows SDK. `xsd.exe orderxml.xml /outputdir:C:\Users\jeroen.mostert\AppData\Local` produces an `orderxml.xsd` file in the specified directory (and `xsd` helpfully says "Writing file"). Double check that the XML file is encoded as UTF-8 and/or try the most recent version of the SDK your OS supports.

Comment: It is encoded as UTF-8. Problem is definitely not in version, i've tried several.

Comment: Then your problem boils down to "I expect the tool to create a file but I can't find it". So either it doesn't create the file, or the file is moved or deleted afterwards, or you're looking in the wrong location. Does XSD say "Writing file" including the location it's writing to? Have you tried other locations? If all else fails, [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) can tell you if the file is created and if not, why not.

Comment: Are you missing the XML encoding definition in your XML file? This should be the first line of your XML file: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: If the above xml snippet is saved into file, then able to view in browser successfully(both in chrome, firefox). So what does your browser complain?

Comment: I think you can run above xml in browser and see the problem

Comment: I was able to run your XML. where did you save it? is it in notepad? did you save it with .xml as extension name?

Comment: Is that real person data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks a lot, problem was - I can't create xsd with above xml, please help me to create it. Answers were - use another version, it was created and then deleted, encoding is wrong.

I found the answer myself, I needed just headings which are usually put above the xml. That much.